# Ideal $I$ contains $p^t$ for some $t>0$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $p$ be a fixed prime integer and $R$ be the set of all rational
>   numbers that can be written in the form $a/b$ with $b$ not divisible
>   by $p$. Prove if $I$ is a nonzero ideal in $R$ and $I \neq R$, then
>   $I$ contains $p^t$ for some $t>0$.

I've proved that $R$ is an integral domain and that $a/b$ is a unit if $p$ does not divide $a$. (Those were parts (a) and (b) of the question and I need help with the part (c), which I stated above.)

Comment: Hey I was wondering, how did you prove (a) and (b)? For (b) is it $a/b\cdot b/a=ab/ba=1_R$ since p doesn't divide a and b so it doesn't divide ab.

Comment: @StillLearning i commented below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $I$ is proper, everything inside of it is not a unit. Since $I$ is nonzero, select a nonzero element of $I$ and write it as $\frac{p^ta}{b}$ where $p$ does not divide $a$. We know $t>0$ because the element is not a unit.

Then $\frac{a}{b}$ is a unit, and $p^t=\frac{b}{a}\frac{p^ta}{b}\in I$.

Comment: Can you also help me proving R is actually PID?

Comment: @Cauchy Show that each ideal is generated by a power of $p$, following all of this work you have been doing.

Comment: @Cauchy How would you start this. Show $I=(p^k)$, by showing $I\subseteq (p^k)$ and $(p^k)\subseteq I$?

Comment: @StillLearning (a) show that R is a subring of Q and then show that R contains Z (b) you are right